# Efficient way to add spaces between characters in a string

Tags: python, string

Say I have a string `s = 'BINGO'`; I want to iterate over the string to produce `'B I N G O'`.

This is what I did:

```
result = ''
for ch in s:
   result = result + ch + ' '
print(result[:-1])    # to rid of space after O
```

Is there a more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: On my machine, this takes about 500ns. Is that really a bottleneck in your program? If not, don't ask about efficiency; ask about simplicity, readability, etc.—things that actually matter.

Comment: @abarnert perhaps *efficient* means something particular to you, but it doesn't *actually* necessarily mean *machine* efficiency.

Comment: @kojiro: "efficient" means something particular in the disciple/profession/hobby/etc. of computer programming, which is what this site is about, so that's the definition that matters. That's why this site has an efficiency tag that's intended and used for exactly that purpose.

Comment: @abarnert actually even in the context of computers it means many things. Besides the ancient dual between storage and speed efficiency, there's a very real precedent for the questions of *coder* efficiency (a.k.a. *productivity*), which is one of the more famous claims about Python, the language in question.

Comment: Yes, @abarnert's right -- the problem with this solution isn't first of all that it's inefficient, it's that it's not Pythonic and not simple. `' '.join(s)` is the simple, Pythonic way. However, efficiency is a concern, as the above solution will be `O(N^2)`, whereas the `join` is `O(N)` -- this won't matter for `'BINGO'` but will matter for long strings.

Comment: @BenHoyt Why do you think OP's method would be more than O(N)? It looks like it only iterates `len(s)` once. Empirically (based on a series of `timeit`s with increasing input string length) it looks more like `O(N)` for the OP's solution and `O(1)` for the `' '.join` and `str.replace` methods.

Comment: @kojiro - yes, it iterates `s` once, but each iteration it needs to build a new `result` string (strings in Python are immutable), so it has to copy between `1` and `len(s)` bytes per loop. So the number of byte copy operations is a triangle, `len(s)*len(s)/2` or `O(len(s)^2)`. *However*, I was surprised how linear it looks with small `N`. It's not until you get to strings of several thousand chars that it really starts to show. See [these results and graph](http://i.imgur.com/1Z21FJP.png) I made using timeit with `len(s)` going between 1000 and 49,000.

Comment: @BenHoyt: The reason it looks linear with smallish strings is that copying a string is basically just a call to memmove—which still loops, of course, but it does so in C code that's usually highly optimized for the platform (especially on x86, which has opcodes specifically designed to speed up memmove). So, the constant multiplier on the second N is orders of magnitude smaller than the one on the first, which makes it hard to see until N gets very large.

Comment: @BenHoyt: But keep in mind that all of the above is dependent on the fact that CPython optimizes str.__add__(str) in a way that the language itself doesn't guarantee, and that, PyPy, Jython, or IronPython may not replicate (although IIRC PyPy has a different optimization with similar effects…).

Comment: @BenHoyt, cpython will append to the string in-place if there is only one reference and enough space. strings are overallocated so this operation is amortized O(1)

Answer (score 74):

```
s = "BINGO"
print(" ".join(s))
```

Should do it.

Comment: explanation from str.join documentation: `S.join(iterable) -> string`

Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
iterable.  **The separator between elements is S.**

Comment: Right, exactly true. Python treats individual strings as an iterable so it will join each character (element in the iterable) with a space.

Answer (score 33):

```
s = "BINGO"
print(s.replace("", " ")[1: -1])
```

Timings below

```
$ python -m timeit -s's = "BINGO"' 's.replace(""," ")[1:-1]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.584 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s's = "BINGO"' '" ".join(s)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 usec per loop
```

Comment: This is interesting, any idea why the replace method is faster?

Comment: @MikeVella At a guess, it might have to do with the fact that Python's source code has a [special case replace handler](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/stringobject.c#L2690) for interleaving when the *from* string is an empty string.

Comment: By the way, I think this answer would be better if it gave `timeit` values for a few different string sizes.

Comment: how can I convert this into putting space every n digits?

Comment: Cool way to do this, but I'm not really sure how it works, can you explain what the brackets on the end add?

Comment: @MikeSchem, the `[1:-1]` doesn't add anything - it removes stuff. If you try without it, you'll see there is are extra spaces at the beginning and end. You could also use `.strip()` depending on your use case.

Comment: Ah, so the replace adds a space before and after as a biproduct, and the [1:-1] pulls them back off.  Thanks!

Comment: I ran this with a much longer string (1.5 million characters) and the replace method was 10x faster than the join method. Normally, I'd prefer the join method as it's more intuitive, but if you're doing this in a hot loop, replace is superior (Python 3.10).

Answer (score 3):

## The Pythonic way

A very pythonic and practical way to do it is by using the string `join()` method:

```
str.join(iterable)
```

The official [Python documentations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) says:

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable... The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

**How to use it?**

*Remember: this is a string method*.

This method will be applied to the `str` above, which reflects the string that will be used as separator of the items in the iterable.

Let's have some practical example!

```
iterable = "BINGO"
separator = " " # A whitespace character.
                # The string to which the method will be applied
separator.join(iterable)
> 'B I N G O'
```

In practice you would do it like this:

```
iterable = "BINGO"    
" ".join(iterable)
> 'B I N G O'
```

But remember that the argument is an iterable, like a string, list, tuple. Although the method returns a string.

```
iterable = ['B', 'I', 'N', 'G', 'O']    
" ".join(iterable)
> 'B I N G O'
```

*What happens if you use a hyphen as a string instead?*

```
iterable = ['B', 'I', 'N', 'G', 'O']    
"-".join(iterable)
> 'B-I-N-G-O'
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to take input make the logic and run

so the code is like this to make your own space maker

```
need = input("Write a string:- ")
result = ''
for character in need:
   result = result + character + ' '
print(result)    # to rid of space after O
```

but if you want to use what python give then use this code

```
need2 = input("Write a string:- ")

print(" ".join(need2))
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
def space_the_chars(string):
    string = string.upper().replace(' ','')
    return string.replace('','  ')[2:-2]


space_the_chars(“I’m going to be spaced”)
```

### the function spaces the string’s characters