# How to reading .txt file , and adding space after specific position / index for each line in python

Tags: python, text-files, readline

I want to read .txt file and add space after a specific position/index for each line. please consider below example for more details.

suppose my file contains

12345 678 91011 12 1314

In the above file, the first row contains space after a specific position/index [4] , then after position/index[8], after position/index[14] and after position/index[17]

Expected output : 
I want every row in the file is having space after a specific position. i.e for the first row, I want to add space after index [2], then add space after index [6], then add space after index[11], then add space after index [21], and so on...

123 45 6 78 91 011 12 131 4

As a reminder, I don't want to replace elements but add a new space after a specific position/index.

add space after a specific position/index for each line a text  file

suppose my file contains :

12345 678 91 011 12 1314

Expected output :

123 45 6 78 91 011 12 131 4

Comment: Hi welcome @bashar, please show us what you have tried so far. We need some code examples to work on.

Comment: thx @mohanys, I want to code for adding space because I did not find something that adds space between specific position .

Comment: @bashar Add whatever you have tried. What do you mean by replacing? Replacing certain characters with another?

Comment: @bashar Here is an example to add spaces between characters [Python adding space between characters in string. Most efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221436/python-adding-space-between-characters-in-string-most-efficient-way)

Comment: @Dennis.M,  I do not want to replace, but add a space in an irregular order between the elements.

Comment: There are too many things for us to guess here. Do the positions depend on the surrounding characters? Should a space be added if that position already contains a space? Between your two examples, can you explain under what circumstances some of these character positions in your requirements changed? If we add a space, should that update the index for the positions later in the string?

Comment: @tripleee, shortly, I would like to add a new "space" column between more than position\index and apply it for all line in a file.

Comment: That's not helping much. Please [edit] the question to explain in detail what you want and how your code so far is looking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Please note that this is the column position/index we are concerned with. This program adds a space between indexes 2 and 3 like you said. You can add the other indexes as you wish:

```
with open("C:/path-to-file/file.txt", "r") as file:
lines = file.read().split("\n")
newlines = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip()
    newline = line[:3] + ' ' + line[3:]   # Add more indexes here
    newlines.append(newline)

with open("C:/path-to-file/file.txt", "w") as newfile:    
    newfile.write("\n".join(newlines))
```

Comment: thx @Max Voisard, This code adds space, but repeats pre-space number 'character' !

Comment: @bashar Not quite sure what you mean by that

Comment: please can you run the latest code, and
 you will see the results.