# Increase character spacing in Matplotlib text?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way I can increase the spacing between characters in matplotlib text?  I mean text in the plot areas, as with `plt.text()`. I tried the `stretch` argument, but the effects are way to subtle, and it's not clear if it's changing the spacing or just making the characters skinnier.  I don't mind manually inserting something between characters if necessary, like a partial space.

Comment: does a larger font size help?

Comment: Not really.  I'm already randomizing on font and font size when generating examples.  What I'm after is spacing between characters relative to the font size.  The default is generally to pack the characters together pretty tightly, but I want examples with them more roomy.

Answer (score 0):

Although a little bet old post, I was working on creating text with justified alignment which had similar component with the above question. I made some rearrangement.

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_text_width(text, ax):
    fig_coor = text.get_window_extent()  #get text box coordination
    inv = ax.transData.inverted()
    data_coor = inv.transform(fig_coor)  #transform to data coordination
    return data_coor[1][0] - data_coor[0][0]

def spaced_text(x, y, text, spacing, ax):
    x_c = x + get_text_width(ax.text(x, y, text[0], alpha = 0), ax) / 2
        #get first letter location with center alignment
    x = x_c
    for letter in text:
        ax.text(x, y, letter, ha = 'center')
        x += spacing

plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
text = 'justified'
spaced_text(1, 5, text, 0.7, plt.gca())
plt.show()
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9BoD.png)

Sometimes, it might also be helpful to use justified alignment to control the spacing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_text_width(text, ax):
    fig_coor = text.get_window_extent()  #get text box coordination
    inv = ax.transData.inverted()
    data_coor = inv.transform(fig_coor)  #transform to data coordination
    return data_coor[1][0] - data_coor[0][0]

def justified_text(x_start, x_end, y, text, ax):
    x_start_c = x_start + get_text_width(ax.text(x_start, y, text[0], alpha = 0), ax) / 2
        #get first letter location with center alignment
    x_end_c = x_end - get_text_width(ax.text(x_end, y, text[-1], ha = 'right', alpha = 0), ax) / 2
        #get last letter location with center alignment
    spacing = (x_end_c - x_start_c) / (len(text) -1)
    x = x_start_c
    for letter in text:
        ax.text(x, y, letter, ha = 'center')
        x += spacing

plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
text = 'justified'
justified_text(1, 5, 7, text, plt.gca())
plt.show()
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Ub0.png)

Answer (score -2):

I found this answer here:
[Python adding space between characters in string. Most efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221436/python-adding-space-between-characters-in-string-most-efficient-way)

```
s = "BINGO"
print(" ".join(s))
```

So for Matplotlib text it would look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.text(0.5, 0.5," ".join('Line 1'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this would only allow increments of a full space, as opposed to various degrees of roominess, if that makes sense. A full space is about the max extreme I'd ever want to go to.

Comment: It's a quick and dirty solution, but assuming you're using python 3 which supports unicode, you can use this method with different width space characters (see for example https://www.brunildo.org/test/space-chars.html)