# How do i add spaces in a string that has been reversed?

Tags: python

So basically, i am trying to get the user to input something like "123" and recieve the output "3 2 1"
but i cant figure out how to add the spaces

```
# current code
number = str(input("Type out a number with more then 1 charachter: "))
print("Original number:", number)
print("Number in reverse:", number[::-1])
```

I apologize in advance, im really new to programming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to add spaces between characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221436/efficient-way-to-add-spaces-between-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print("Number in reverse:", ' '.join(number[::-1]))
```

Or use an iterator `reversed`:

```
print("Number in reverse:", ' '.join(reversed(number)))
```

Comment: [`str.join` is typically less performant with a generator than with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print("Number in reverse:", " ".join(number[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.join`:

```
print("Number in reverse:", ' '.join(number[::-1]))
```

Here a space or `' '` is added between the characters.

> The join() method returns a string created by joining the elements of
> an iterable by string separator. exmaples for iterable objects are
> strings and lists.