# How do I add a space between characters when a condition is met?

Tags: python, delimiter, cjk

I want to add a space when two adjacent glyphs are not of the same type. In my case, I am trying to get it to work for Japanese Hiragana and Katakana.

So if I input 'これはペンです', I'll get 'これは　ペン です' because は and ペ are not of the same type and ン and で are not of the same type. Likewise, if I input '日本人です', I should get '日本人 です' because 人　and で are not of the same type. The glyphs '日本人' are left alone because they're not members of the Hiragana and Katakana set.

Do I need to make a list of glyphs for Hiragana and Katakana? (This is no problem, by the way.) Is there a way designating an 'elsewhere list' of all things that belong to neither Hiragana and Katakana?

**Disclaimer:** I'm a linguist and I'm fairly new to programming. I know how it works, but I don't have a ton of hands-on experience. Also, I'm not looking for an extant parser or something like that.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: See [Efficient way to add spaces between characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221436/efficient-way-to-add-spaces-between-characters-in-a-string) for a possible answer

Comment: You could create a list of glyphs for each type and a list for the others. When two adjacent glyphs are not from the same list you can insert a space

Comment: I believe you are headed in the right direction. Creating a list of glyphs for Hiragan and Katakana should suffice. If a glyph isn't in either list then I would assume it would be "elsewhere list" so there probably isn't a need to maintain that list separately. At that point it's just a matter of iterating through your input and search the lists to compare and adding a space when your condition is hit.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Unicode map of Japanese characters]

The Hiragana and Katakana characters are contiguous: it is very easy to calculate whether a code point is within a specific set. Basically if a codepoint is between 0x3041 and 0x309F it is Hiragana. It if is between 0x30A1 and 0x30FF then it is Katakana. No list required.

Comment: [Possible implementation](https://tio.run/##NcwhDsIwFAZg31P87q3JQpbMEAKCe5CQbbBRwvqat05MllkcCi6ARHCkHqQYUJ/73ORPbMulk5Ra4R7GH8UzXwaY3rF4dMKjqyelBmxAMdzj9RbDO87POH9ieMXwIKWcGOszAi3ObGxGPzuNlgX7HB2M/V/ZkONS9fWhQrNCgzVoN5bFtiCtdUpf).

Comment: What's up with 0x3040 and 0x30A0? Do they belong to the blocks but are unused or so?

Comment: 0x3040 is indeed empty. 0x30A0 seems to be a valid character though: ゠

Comment: [Another way](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurWMFWQf1x4@THTT2PG9c/bp71uHnz48bljxtnqnNxZWQWJaYn5iWC1ETHlBobmBjogihLt1h1ruzEksRsZElHiKQbSJKroCgzr0SjKFWvuDRJI01dw97GthpmXK2mhr1tNUx/rWYNWBbBB8ki1KrrKKgrAIliTc3//wE).

Comment: 0x30A0, the double hyphen, is used as an interpunct to separate words, or in place of a single hyphen during transliteration where it may be confused for the chōonpu - U+30FC ー KATAKANA-HIRAGANA PROLONGED SOUND MARK